# Receiving Data On Sinatra Server

Tags: java, ruby, sinatra, client

I am able to send data to a sinatra server (Strings) but I'm not sure about how to actually receive it in the sinatra code. Could anyone help?

Java client (what i'm using to send data) code:

```
private static void contactServer() {
    try {
        String text = "This is a text please work";
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 4567);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4567/hello");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os);
        writer.flush();
        writer.write(text);
        url.openStream();
        System.out.println("done");
        String strTemp = "";
        /*while(null != (strTemp = br.readLine())){
            System.out.println(strTemp);
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work.  Sinatra's server understands and speaks a language called *the http protocol*, so sending the string:

```
"This is a text please work"
```

through a socket to a Sinatra app is a hopeless prayer.

A protocol is a set of rules that specify how the client and the server will speak to each other--then each party can understand exactly what other party is saying.  For the http protocol, clients send something known as `a request`, and servers reply with something known as `a response`.   The request and the response must be formatted precisely according to the rules specified by the http protocol. The gory details for a request are here:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

So your java program needs to send `a request` to Sinatra's server, which is simply a string formatted in a precise manner.  Here is what a simple GET request looks like:

```
GET /path/to/page HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4567
```

If you want to make a GET request for the page:

```
http://localhost:4567/page1
```

(i.e. hit the Sinatra route `get '/page1'`)

...then a simple GET request for that page would look like:

```
GET /page1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4567
```

Also, you must end every line in the http request with "\r\n" no matter what OS you are using.  Those two characters are part of the http protocol.  Furthermore, after the last header there must be a blank line signified by another "\r\n", like this:

```
GET /page1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:4567\r\n\r\n
```

Here is the java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Sinatra {
    private static void contactServer() {
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 4567); 
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os);

            String[] text = {
                "GET /page1 HTTP/1.1",
                "Host: localhost:4567",
            };

            String request = "";

            for(int i=0; i < text.length; ++i) {
                request += text[i] + "\r\n";
            }

            request += "\r\n";

            System.out.println(request);

            writer.write(request);
            writer.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sinatra.contactServer();
    }

}
```

Note: the first few times I ran that java program, the server(which I started with `$ ruby myapp.rb`) threw the following error:

```
[2013-08-19 20:10:11] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
    /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
    /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
    /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

But when I ran the java program a few more times, the server eventually behaved.  I have no idea what is causing that error.  When I entered the url in FireFox, the server never threw that error.  So I used Firebug to look at the request that Firefox sends; then I used all the same request headers in the java program, but the server still threw that error.

**Edit:** I can get the server error to go away by making the java program sleep for 1 second before closing the socket.  The socket closes when you explicitly close the socket or when the program ends.  Without the sleep, I think the socket closes while the server is still processing the request.  Because a browser keeps the socket open, a browser never causes the server to throw that error.

The same server error also occurs with a ruby client:

```
require 'socket'

port = 4567
host = 'localhost'
s = TCPSocket.new host, port 

req = [
 "GET /page1 HTTP/1.1",
 "Host: localhost:4567",
 "Accept: */*",
]

req = req.join("\r\n") << ("\r\n" * 2)
print req

s.write req
s.flush
#sleep(1)
s.close
```

And the fix is the same.  The only niggling detail is why the `curl` unix command doesn't cause the server to throw that error:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:4567/page1
* About to connect() to localhost port 4567 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4567 (#0)
> GET /page1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost:4567
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 0
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20)
< Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 04:59:16 GMT
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

With the -v option, curl prints out the request and the response.  Using curl to make the request, I never saw the sever throw that error.  I wonder if curl does a sleep too?